# How to separate histories for different Helm prompts

Tags: helm

> When operating as **separate** Doctor Fates, Inza wears the **helm**et and
>   Kent's original costume while...

– *Google on `helm separate history`*

---

When I press <kbd>M-p</kbd> in the Helm prompt for `helm-git-grep` I get a file path I entered previously in `helm-find-files`:

[image]

What I would really like to see is the pattern I searched with previously in `helm-git-grep`.

How to make Helm have separate mini-buffer histories for different kinds of Helm (`helm-M-x`, `helm-mini`, `helm-git-grep` and `helm-find-files`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm has support for different histories which is already used quite heavily in the main helm package as well as some of the 3rd party helms. From the the helm manual:

```
:history

By default all minibuffer input is pushed to `minibuffer-history',
if an argument HISTORY is provided, input will be pushed to HISTORY.
History element should be a symbol.
```

For example the `helm-apt` function calls helm with:

```
(helm :sources 'helm-source-apt
          :prompt "Search Package: "
          :input query
          :buffer "*helm apt*"
          :history 'helm-apt-input-history)
```

So you can simply redefine the helm calls to include a reference to a new history variable. In the longer term it might make more sense to submit patches to the various projects to use this feature. For example `helm-grep` and `helm-ag` may well want to share generic `helm-search-history` variable?

Comment: Ah, so it's an issue with helm-git-grep? I'll try to send them a patch as you suggested. And thanks for the workaround!